# How to get HTTP stack type of HttpWebRequest for a rest request in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am using Silverlight 4 using C# 4.0.

I have a `HttpwebRequest` object which is created using following statement

```
var webRequest = (httpStackType == HttpStack.Browser)
               ? (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp.Create(requestUri)
               : (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(requestUri);
```

At later stage of in my program where I do not have access to `httpStackType` variable, I want to find out what type of HttpStack is used for this `webRequest`, how can I find this, is there a property or method to get the `HttpStack` type for `HttpwebRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:-

```
 if (webRequest.GetType().Name == "BrowserHttpWebRequest")
 {

 }
 else
 {

 }
```